# Concatenate all rows of a numpy matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy matrix and would like to concatenate all of the rows together so I end up with one long array.

```
#example

input:
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6}
 [7 8 9]]

output:
[[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]
```

The way I am doing it now doe not seem pythonic.  I'm sure there is a better way.

```
combined_x = x[0] 
for index, row in enumerate(x):
    if index!= 0:
        combined_x = np.concatenate((combined_x,x[index]),axis=1)
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: @senderle -- ravel was my first instinct too.  Post as an answer and I'll happily upvote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest the [`ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) or [`flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy.ndarray.flatten) method of `ndarray`.

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> a.ravel()
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

`ravel` is faster than `concatenate` and `flatten` because it doesn't return a copy unless it has to:

```
>>> a.ravel()[5] = 99
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4, 99],
       [ 6,  7,  8]])
>>> a.flatten()[5] = 77
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4, 99],
       [ 6,  7,  8]])
```

But if you need a copy to avoid the memory sharing illustrated above, you're better off using `flatten` than `concatenate`, as you can see from these timings:

```
>>> %timeit a.ravel()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 468 ns per loop
>>> %timeit a.flatten()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 us per loop
>>> %timeit numpy.concatenate(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.26 us per loop
```

Note also that you can achieve the *exact* result that your output illustrates (a one-row 2-d array) with `reshape` (thanks Pierre GM!):

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> a.reshape(1, -1)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
>>> %timeit a.reshape(1, -1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 736 ns per loop
```

Comment: Note that `ravel` or `flatten` will transform your 2D array to a 1D array --- ie, switching from a `(N,M)` to a `(N*M,)` shape. The OP may want to add a `.reshape(1,-1)` to force the output to a 2D array (1 row, many columns).

Comment: Of course, if you want to just transform your 2D array into a 1D one, the faster is `your_array.shape = -1`...

Comment: @PierreGM, thanks for pointing out the difference in output. Regarding `your_array.shape` -- I did some more informal timings that agree that `your_array.shape = (-1,)` is a bit faster than `your_array.reshape((-1,))` -- probably because the latter creates a new view. But somewhat surprisingly, `your_array.shape = -1` is twice as slow as `your_array.shape = (-1,)`.

Comment: The timing difference is a bit surprising. Using `-1` or `(-1,)` is a shortcut anyway, we should probably use `your_array.size` or `(your_array.size,)` to skip a test...

Answer (score 6):

You could use the numpy [`concatenate` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
>>> ar = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> np.concatenate(ar)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

You could also try [`flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy.ndarray.flatten):

```
>>> ar.flatten()
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: Seems exactly what the user wants.