# How can i iteratively stack rows in numpy using for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vstack

I am trying to iteratively add rows to my two dimensional np.array

```
A = np.zeros((1,14),dtype = float)
for i in arr:
    A = np.vstack(fn(i))# function returns array
```

And as a result i always get only last array i stacked
Can someone please explain me how to stack all rows and why is this not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate all rows of a numpy matrix in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252781/concatenate-all-rows-of-a-numpy-matrix-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `vstack` while iterating, as it will artificially increase memory usage, as explained in [this similar question but related to pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36489576/6692898).

Secondly, assuming `fn(i)` returns a new array that you want to append to `A`, then that line should be `A = np.vstack((A, fn(i))`

Considering all this, a better option would be to create and collect all your arrays into a list that you can later stack.

```
A = np.zeros((1, 14), dtype=float)
arrays = [A] + [fn(i) for i in arr] # assuming `arr` is an iterable
A = np.vstack(tuple(arrays))
```

You can read more in the [numpy.vstack docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

Comment: It's useful although I don't think usage growth is exponential. It's rather a quadratic one.

Answer (score 0):

You must add A on vstack:

```
A = np.zeros((1,14),dtype = float)
for i in arr:
    A = np.vstack([A,fn(i)])# function returns array
```